# export string variable as xml file

Tags: python, xml

I have a string variable (xmlcontents) containing data which I want to convert it to xml  I used fromstring function and changed the type from string to etree.ElementTree.Element type but I cant export it as a file can you help with exporting the variable myxml?

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML, fromstring
myxml = fromstring(xmlcontents)
```

Comment: the code should work with, what is exactly the error?

Comment: It works but I want to export xml file to my directory but I don't know how

Answer (score 2):

1. Firstly, if `xmlcontents` is just correct xml file - you can just
   write it back to file as string :)

   ```
   with open('somefile.xml', 'w') as the_file:
       the_file.write(xmlcontents)
   ```
2. Secondly, use `ElementTree`:

   ```
   from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML, fromstring, ElementTree
   myxml = fromstring(xmlcontents)
   ElementTree(myxml).write('output.xml')
   ```

Comment: Note that generally, if the OP isn't making it clear what they're asking in their question, it's better to get the question clarified and not answer it until it is. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).